# Timer on iOS doesn't work

Tags: ios, timer

I'm trying to make a timer by myself but it doesn't work. It seems like it goes nil every time it repeats, anyone?  It works on OS X but not on iOS.

I just need a working **loop method** - any suggestions?

Header:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timerOutlet;
- (void)timer:(id)sender;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
@synthesize timerOutlet;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    started = TRUE;
    [self timer:nil];
}

- (void)timer:(id)sender {
    int test = 1;
    NSString *number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",test];
    timerOutlet.text = number;
    [self performSelector:@selector(timer:) withObject:Nil afterDelay:1.0];
    test ++;                
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you re-declare `test` and assign 1 to it every time the timer method executes. So if you either omit the declaration and make `test` an instance variable, or make it `static`, that should help. Apart from that, however, you should really use an NSTimer object instead of raping the framework.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    started = TRUE;
    test = 1;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(timer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)timer:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%i",test);
    test++;
}
```

Comment: OMG how could i be so stupid! -.-' Thanks!! haha i'll just use NStimer method

Comment: @user1637253 no problem, that's nothing -- see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221901/search-label-text-with-uitextfield/12221930#12221930)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot "static" in int test = 1;

```
static int test = 1;
```

and you should be happy.

Comment: do not init test variable on each function launch. So it will be initiated only one time. Not good solution, but this timer idea not good at all... )))

Comment: I know that - see my answer (and reputation). I meant, you should write the explanation into your answer to educate the OP who posted the question :)

Comment: THANKS!! that was the problem ... haha some times you can't handle the code.. haha