# 'Search' label text with UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uilabel

I've got a UILabel and a UITextField. Each time the user enters text in the field, I need to check weather the textfield text exists in the label's text (basically I'm searching the label's text) . I was using

```
NSRange range = [sentenceRequestLabel.text rangeOfString:resultString];
if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"string was found");
} else {
    NSLog(@"string was not found");
}
```

to check (resultString being the textfield.text), but even if the label text in the text field is not even close to the label's text NSLog says "string was found". Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"string was found");
```

means "If string was not found, then print it was found". That `==` should be a `!=`.

Comment: That was my initial reaction, but when I did change it to '!=', now every single time it prints "string was not found" no matter what the text is.

Comment: @JohnWickham could you please post a bit more code with context?

Comment: Sure thing...  

Attached to the textfield's ValueDidChange action, I have:

Comment: -(void)evaluateString {
    
    resultString = blindfield.text;
    NSRange range = [sentenceRequestLabel.text rangeOfString:resultString];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"string was found");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"string was not found");
    }
}

Comment: @JohnWickham in this case are you sure that `blindfield` and `blindfield.text` is not nil?

Comment: I assumed it would not be since the only way to trigger the evaulateString method is to enter some value in the field...

Comment: @JohnWickham please NSLog both of the texts. Also mind that `[sentenceRequestLabel.text rangeOfString:resultString]` is not the same as `[resultString rangeOfString:sentenceRequestLabel.text]`.

Comment: you're right, when I NSLog the strings, resultString actually says "(null)abc" (when I entered abc in the field).

Comment: @JohnWickham then you need to create and initialize the label in order to have some actual text inside.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works perfectly now! Except sometimes the sentenceRequestLabel.text has a space character in it (for example "Roses are red"). When I type "Roses" in the field, it works well and says the string was found. But when I type a space, it says the string was not found. Whats wrong?

Comment: @John it's strange indeed. Try logging the strings again, there might be some other characters...

Comment: Ah, I should've caught this before. It's case sensitive!

Comment: @John try rangeOfString:options: or similar (fire up the docs ;)